# How to write a PL/SQL procedure with an Instead Of Trigger as Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I wrote a PL/SQL function and am using dynamic SQL to execute a Create trigger statement as follows :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION register_driver1(driver_name IN VARCHAR, pass_word IN VARCHAR) RETURN NUMBER AS
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(500);
driver_id NUMBER;
new_view_name VARCHAR(50);   --<-----Line 4
BEGIN
--function statements

sql_stmt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reg_vehicle 
                 INSTEAD OF INSERT ON '||new_view_name||
               ' FOR EACH ROW 
                 DECLARE 
                 vehicle_id NUMBER;
                 BEGIN
                 vehicle_id := vehicle_ids.nextval
                 INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(:NEW.Model, :NEW.Seats, :NEW.reg_no, vehicle_id, '||driver_id||');
                 END;';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;  --<-----Line 32

--Remaining function body
END;
/
```

Here, the variables `new_view_name, driver_id` are defined above this code snippet. `Vehicle` is a table`(Model, Seats, Reg_no, vehicel_id, driver_id)` and `reg_vehicle(Model, Seats, Reg_no)`  is a view having `Vehicle`s of a particular `driver_id`.

`vehicle_ids` is a sequence created outside the procedure.

The above shows compilation error at the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` line. What is the correct way to do this?

The error shown when function is called with some driver_name and pass_word:-

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.REGISTER_DRIVER1", line 32 ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Comment: Why are you creating the trigger this way? It seems unusual and not the way you'd normally go about creating objects. I'd be very surprised if you really needed dynamic sql and couldn't create it in a sql script instead.

Comment: Your trigger statement won't compile. It's missing a semi-colon. This is why dynamic SQL is hard: compilation errors are disguised as runtime errors. Although it doesn't seem that is the cause of the error you have, it's just a pleasant surprise for you once you have fixed this one ;-)

Comment: But I agree with @Boneist and Littlefoot. This whole piece of code is misconceived. Shouldn't be a function. Shouldn't be creating a trigger using dynamic SQL. Shouldn't be creating a trigger with a hardcoded ID value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't recommend creating objects *dynamically*.

If you - for some reason - insist on that, then another problem: you can't perform DDL here as you'd call a function as e.g.

```
select register_driver1(...) from dual;
```

and get

> ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML

So - switch to a procedure with an OUT parameter to return whatever that function is supposed to return.

---

As of error you got: you miss `BEGIN`. Something like this *compiles*:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE register_driver1 (driver_name  IN VARCHAR,
  2                                                pass_word    IN VARCHAR)
  3  AS
  4     sql_stmt       VARCHAR2 (500);
  5     driver_id      NUMBER;
  6     new_view_name  VARCHAR (50);
  7  BEGIN
  8     sql_stmt :=
  9           'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reg_vehicle
 10                   INSTEAD OF INSERT ON '
 11        || new_view_name
 12        || ' FOR EACH ROW
 13                   DECLARE
 14                   vehicle_id NUMBER;
 15                   BEGIN
 16                   vehicle_id := vehicle_ids.nextval
 17                   INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(:NEW.Model, :NEW.Seats, :NEW.reg_no, vehicle_id, '
 18        || driver_id
 19        || ');
 20                   END;';
 21
 22     -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
 23     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (sql_stmt);
 24  END;
 25  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> EXEC register_driver1('a', 'b');
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reg_vehicle
                 INSTEAD OF INSERT ON  FOR
EACH ROW
                 DECLARE
                 vehicle_id NUMBER;

BEGIN
                 vehicle_id := vehicle_ids.nextval
                 INSERT
INTO Vehicles VALUES(:NEW.Model, :NEW.Seats, :NEW.reg_no, vehicle_id, );

END;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I have written the begin and end at line 7 and 24. Just not shown in above question. The error is ```ORA-24344: success with compilation error ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.REGISTER_DRIVER1", line 32 ORA-06512: at line 4```

Comment: Please see the updated question. Thank you very much @Littlefoot :)

Comment: Compilation works OK - I tried it, no problem. But - as if you didn't read what I said: you can't use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE + DDL in a **function**. Should have been a **procedure**.